# Using prefix as parameter in fa forward

Tags: struts

Is there any way i can use a prefix as a paramter or in the path of a forward like:

```
<forward name="test" path="/switch.do&page='/test.do'&prefix='/test'"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you use request or session attribute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is meant with `prefix`, I assume you are referring to the servlet's name. Suppose you have this *forward* in your `struts-config.xml` as part of an `action` mapping:

```
<forward name="test" path="/switch" />
```

If you want to get the *forwards'* names available to your action, you can get them with `mapping.findForwards()`.

If you already have a `forward`, for example:

```
ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("test");
```

you can get the name of the forward with:

```
String fwdName = forward.getName(); // returns "test"
```

and the servlet name or path with:

```
String servletPath = forward.getPath(); // returns "/switch.do"
```

you can also get it from the `request` object:

```
String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
```

OK, now, if you want to modify the forward before returning control to Struts, so that you can append extra parameters, you'll need to create a new `ActionForward` based on one of the forwards defined in your `struts-config.xml`, like for example:

```
ActionForward forward = mapping.findForward("test");
StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(forward.getPath());
path.append("?id=");
path.append(someobject.getId());
return new ActionForward(path.toString(), true); // `true` means "do a redirect"
```

This would tell Struts to issue a redirect to an URL like `/switch.do?id=3`

Knowing how to create a new `ActionForward`, and how to get the names of the forwards and the servlet names they point to, you shouldn't have a problem constructing the forward that you need.